# SELECT in SQL QUERY - is it possible

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to `SELECT` name and address attribute from names table but at the same time I also want to combine description attribute from info table.

```
CREATE TABLE names(
ID CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY
name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
address VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE info (
ID CHAR(2) REFERENCES names
description VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL
)
```

I Tried `union` method but failed

```
 SELECT name, address
FROM names
UNION
SELECT description
FROM info;
```

is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name, address, description
FROM names JOIN info USING(id)
```

Comment: @AnishShah: Accepting an answer is up to the OP. There is no need to request it.

Comment: i couldnt accept it until 15 min i dunno why ask the website owner but now its done @AnishShah

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `full outer join`:

```
SELECT  n.name
,       n.address
,       i.description
FROM    names n
FULL OUTER JOIN
        info i
ON      i.id = n.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called a join

```
SELECT n.name, n.address, i.description
FROM names n
join info i on n.id = i.id
```

Answer (score 0):

select n.name, n.address, i.description from names as n
Left join info as i on n.id = i.id